# Printing starting and ending threads in mergesort

Tags: c++, multithreading, mergesort

I have a general mergesort code that sorts 8 integers in C++. The sorting part works fine. However, I need to implement threads. To be specific, I am trying to do the following:
-Print out when a thread has started and ended.
-In the situation that a thread has finished, I need to print out the numbers that are sorted.
An example of the desired output is the following:

```
Thread 1 started
Thread 2 started
Thread 3 started
Thread 4 started
Thread 6 started
Thread 7 started
Thread 9 started
Thread 9 finished: 7,
Thread 8 started
Thread 8 finished: 3,
Thread 11 started
Thread 11 finished: 1,
........
........
........
Thread 1 finished: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
```

I need help implementing this. I defined my threads as follows:

```
thread * t1 = new thread;
thread * t2 = new thread;
*t1 = thread(&mergesort,array,low,mid);
*t2 = thread(&mergesort,array,mid+1,high);
t1->join();
t2->join();
```

I use the following to print the thread:

```
cout<<"Thread "<<this_thread::get_id()<<" started"<<endl;
```

Within int main(), I placed the code to print the ordered numbers. My problem is that I never get the desired output. I believe my main mistake is placing the cout functions for the threads in the wrong places. Any help would greatly be appreciated.